# How the RowDetails do not show when selecting several datagird's rows in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I used RowDetails in Datagrid for show my table .My DataGrid xml code is :

```
    <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailTemplate" x:Name="rowTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="RowDetailGrid"
              Width="750"
              Height="Auto"
              Margin="5">

            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    CornerRadius="5">

                <Grid>
                    <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <DataGrid 
                               x:Name="dginfo"

                          HeadersVisibility="All" 
                         Margin="2,0,2,2"
                         GridLinesVisibility="All"
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          CanUserAddRows="False"
                          CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                          CanUserResizeRows="False"
                          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                          IsReadOnly="True"
                           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 


                          SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                          TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LoadingRow="MetroDataGrid_LoadingRow" Width="700" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Height="auto" Loaded="dginfo_Loaded">

                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="مقدار" Binding="{Binding m1}" Width="*">
                                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                </DataGridTextColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />
                                    <Setter Property="Height"  Value="auto" />
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.m0, 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="CornflowerBlue" />-->
                                </Style>
                            </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>    
                          <DataGrid x:Name="MetroDataGrid"
                                HeadersVisibility="All" 
                                Margin="2,0,2,2"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                                CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                GridLinesVisibility="All"
                                EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                                EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource RowDetailTemplate}"
                                RowDetailsVisibilityChanged="dataGrid1_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged"
                                RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                Loaded="dataGrid1_Loaded"
                                TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" LoadingRow="MetroDataGrid_LoadingRow" SelectedCellsChanged="MetroDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="تصویر" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Pics}" Width="40" Height="40" />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KalaID}" Header="شناسه "  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KalaName}" Header="نام"  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>

                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding catName}" Header="دسته بندی "  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding proCode}" Header="Product Code "  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KalaTedad}" Header="تعداد"  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn  Binding="{Binding KalaPrice}" Header="قیمت واحد " Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                            <Style>
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>

                                            </Style>
                                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KalaMinTozihat}" Header="توضیحات" Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>

                                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KalaDate, StringFormat=yyyy/MM/dd}" Header="تاریخ ثبت"  Width="3*" FrameworkElement.FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight"  Value="Bold" />

                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Context_Delete"/>

                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="35"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                                <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ToggleButton x:Name="RowHeaderToggleButton"
                                            Click="ToggleButton_Click"
                                            Cursor="Hand" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                            </DataGrid>
```

And methods are :

```
     private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            // the original source is what was clicked.  For example 
            // a button.
            DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree upwards looking for
            // the clicked row.
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            // if we found the clicked row
            if (dep != null && dep is DataGridRow)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;
                KalaClass krow = (KalaClass)row.Item;
                if (krow != null)
                {
                    IQueryable<product> q = from p in entity.Products
                                            where p.productID == krow.KalaID
                                            select p;

                    curentProduct = q.First();
                }
                if (MetroDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    return;
                }
                // change the details visibility
                if (row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            //dgRowProFill(curentProduct);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }

    private void dataGrid1_RowDetailsVisibilityChanged(object sender, DataGridRowDetailsEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            DataGridRow row = e.Row as DataGridRow;
            if (MetroDataGrid.SelectedItems.Count > 1)
            {

                return;
            }
            dg.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            KalaClass krow = (KalaClass)MetroDataGrid.SelectedItem;

            if (krow != null)
                curentProduct = findProductByid(krow.KalaID);

            FrameworkElement tb = GetTemplateChildByName(row, "RowHeaderToggleButton");
            if (tb != null)
            {

                if (row.DetailsVisibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
                {
                    (tb as ToggleButton).IsChecked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    (tb as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;
                }
            }
            // dginfo_Loaded(dg);
            //dgRowProFill(curentProduct);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
    public static FrameworkElement GetTemplateChildByName(DependencyObject parent, string name)
    {


        int childnum = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < childnum; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is FrameworkElement &&

                    ((FrameworkElement)child).Name == name)
            {
                return child as FrameworkElement;
            }
            else
            {
                var s = GetTemplateChildByName(child, name);
                if (s != null)
                    return s;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void MetroDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            KalaClass krow = (KalaClass)MetroDataGrid.SelectedItem;
            if (krow != null)
            {
                IQueryable<product> q = from p in entity.Products
                                        where p.productID == krow.KalaID
                                        select p;

                curentProduct = q.First();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }


    }
```

It's work succesfully like below :

[image]

When I selected several rows :

[image]

But I want doesn't show RowDetails when I selecting several rows and Doesn't load inner Datagird. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed RowDetailsVisibilityMode to Collapsed and Change ToggleButton_Click method like below :

```
      private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            // the original source is what was clicked.  For example 
            // a button.
            DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree upwards looking for
            // the clicked row.
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            // if we found the clicked row
            if (dep != null && dep is DataGridRow)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dep;


                // change the details visibility
                if (row.DetailsVisibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    KalaClass krow = (KalaClass)row.Item;
                    if (krow != null)
                    {
                        IQueryable<product> q = from p in entity.Products
                                                where p.productID == krow.KalaID
                                                select p;

                        curentProduct = q.First();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    row.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            //dgRowProFill(curentProduct);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

So It's work successfully when I click multi row .